# Shopify shop not defined

Tags: vue.js, shopify

I have a problem with my code for shopify. The website used to work untill today and all the products are not showing on the website. I have a model where the graphql get's the products from shopify

```html
query {
        shop {
          name
          description
          products(first: 50, query:"available_for_sale:true", reverse: true, sortKey:CREATED_AT) {
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
              hasPreviousPage
            }
            edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                productType
                availableForSale
                tags
                options {
                  name
                  values
                }
                variants(first: 5) {
                  pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                    hasPreviousPage
                  }
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      title
                      image {
                        src
                      }
                      price
                    }
                  }
                }
                collections(first: 5) {
                  pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                    hasPreviousPage
                  }
                  edges {
                    node {
                      title
                    }
                  }
                }
                images(first: 5) {
                  pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                    hasPreviousPage
                  }
                  edges {
                    node {
                      src
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I have a controller where all the products are processed but i get the errors in the controller. Below i have the promise from the code above

```html
 const shopNameAndProductsPromise = cartModel
      .shopNameAndProductsPromise()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.model);
        return result.model.shop;
      });
```

And i get the error on result.model.shop.

If i remove the shop from the graphql i get errors on the code below with cart.attrs not defined. or shop.attrs.products not defined

```html
const data = {
        cart: cart.attrs,
        checkoutId: req.query.checkoutId,
        products: shop.attrs.products,
        productsTags: products.data.products.edges,
        shop: shop.attrs,
        isCartOpen: req.query.cart,
        categories: tags.data.shop.productTags.edges,
        collections: collections.data.collections.edges,
        todayInfo: todayInfo,
        todayActive: todayActive,
      };
```

Does anyone have solutions for this, thanks!